# Cannot mv to a subdirectory of itself

Tags: shell-script, files, mv

I am running this simple script and I am trying to create a cron job so that the file gets copied to my thumbdrive (with the new name)

```
  sudo cp /home/pi/NewLog.log /media/usb
  sleep 20
  cd /media/usb
  sudo mv -f NewLog.log NewLog-$(date '+%FT%T').log
  sudo cp /dev/null /home/pi/NewLog.log
```

But I am getting the error

mv: cannot move ‘NewLog.log’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘NewLog-2016-05-04T14:19:24.log’

ls -l in /media/usb shows this,

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   42747 Nov 30 16:18 backup xml.txt   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  407517 Apr 28 11:07 Comparision log.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4174 Apr 29 18:16 Friday.txt
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   16384 May  4 14:12 Logs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  594588 May  3 09:28 MachineHMAX___.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  737280 May  4 17:23 NewLog.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  415960 May  3 10:21 NewLog__.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  267989 Apr 28 09:28 NewLog.txt
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   16384 May 17  2015 System Volume Information
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  276588 Apr 29 11:05 Thur_a.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  183600 Apr 29 11:05 Thur_b.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  276370 Apr 28 11:22 Thurs.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  460185 Apr 28 13:42 Thur.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  676739 May  3 13:44 Tuesday.Log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    8032 Apr 23 17:36 unix2dos.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7364727 May  4 08:45 Wednesday.txt
```

Comment: Beside the issue, is there a reason you don't just run `sudo cp /home/pi/NewLog.log /media/usb/NewLog-$(date '+%FT%T').log` ?

Comment: No, when i did that it says cannot create regular file. I want the file to be timestamped and copied to the USB everyday at a particular time and then i clear the file ,

Comment: so you are not even able to copy the file to media ?

Comment: Well i am able to cp if I do sudo cp /home/pi/NewLog.log /media/usb....but if I try the first comment its not working

Comment: After you do the first 3 steps, what do you see if you do `ls -l`?

Comment: I find NewLog.log file in the /media/usb and i cross checked the file and its getting copied.The permissions are -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root

Comment: You don't see anything else in the directory? Please post the entire `ls -l` output in the question.

Comment: The error you get would happen if `NewLog-2016-05-04T14:19:24.log` already existed and was a directory or a symbolic link to a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon (`:`) character is not a valid character in file names on a FAT/VFAT filesystem. The `rename` system call (which is what `mv` calls under the hood) returns the EINVAL status code to indicate this. Attempting to move a directory to become a subdirectory of itself returns the same status code; `mv` only lists one of the possible error reasons.

Use a different time format. The ISO 8601 format may be a formal standard, but its punctuated form is annoying to deal with. Use the unpunctuated form, or another representation altogether. You aren't currently following ISO 8601 anyway since you omitted the timezone indication, which is bad since it makes the time ambiguous. This form is ISO-compliant, uses UTC time, and doesn't include any punctuation:

```
date -u '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ'
```